Using RxJS to handle incoming stream
As a beginner in using reactive concepts, and in using Angular in general, I found myself in a bind regarding streams. I've built a really simple backend endpoint with Spring to handle range requests, so I can stream audio files to my frontend. However I haven' t been able to figure out how to take advantage of my file being sent chunk by chunk.
My service function that handles everything:
async receiveSong(): Promise<Blob>{
     let response : Response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/song/stream/1",{
      method:"GET",
      headers:{
        "Content-Type":"text/plain",
        "Range":"0-50000",
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }
    });

     let array:Array<Uint8Array> = [];
    // @ts-ignore
    for await (const chunk of response.body){
      array.push(chunk);
    }
    array = array.concat()
    return new Blob(array, {type: "audio/mpeg"})
  }

But with this I can only send 1 chunk to my audio player, and I'm not sure how can I refresh my audio Blob without reloading the page (or the resource the very least)
This is how I set the resource URL that I pass into my  tag in html
this.songService.receiveSong().then(blob => this.songURL =  URL.createObjectURL(blob));

